# Proving that an operator is hermitian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

Let $A$ be an operator that is the product of two hermitian operators.
Am I at liberty to say that if those two hermitian operators commute and their commutator is zero, then $A$ is hermitian?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Let $A=BC$, where $B$ and $C$ are individually hermitian, and $[B,C]=0$.  Then you have:
$$A^{\dagger}=(BC)^{\dagger}=C^{\dagger}B^{\dagger}=CB=BC=A.$$